# query where regexp in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm using laravel 5
And I want to run this query

```
SELECT *
                FROM `discussions`
                WHERE
                  `title` REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', REPLACE('".$term."', ' ', '[[:>:]].*[[:<:]]'), '[[:>:]]')
```

I tried this

```
Discussion::where('title', 'REGEXP', "CONCAT('[[:<:]]', REPLACE('".$term."', ' ', '[[:>:]].*[[:<:]]'), '[[:>:]]')")->get();
```

But I did not get back anything (not even an error)
Can this be done?

Comment: You're going to have to use `whereRaw()` queries, Laravel doesn't have those functions built-in.