# Laravel 5 whereRaw regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to do a `whereRaw` lookup on a table using a regular expression in Laravel 5.  The code I am trying is:

```
whereRaw("'/admin' REGEXP action.regex")
```

With the above code I get the following error:

```
Undefined index: column
```

What I am trying to do is compare the current URL with a regex value stored in the database.  For example the URL path i'm passing in is:

```
/admin
```

The field that holds the regex is:

```
action.regex
```

The regex looks like this:

```
#^/admin$#s
```

**How can I achieve what want?**

Comment: Can you show your query? (eg. ->toSql();)

Comment: Maybe you can find something here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829687/query-where-regexp-in-laravel-eloquent

Answer (score 0):

I believe your syntax for regular expression is incorrect. They are not completely the same as PCRE. For example, no need in `#` delimiters.

Check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) official docs on them.

But anyway, this `Undefined index: column` is produced by something other than database I think. Check the result of `->toSql()` call on your query (remove `->get()` first).